# How to find duplicate users from Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to find duplicate users present in Azure AD? How can I find them directly from Azure portal. THanks

Comment: What's the criteria for duplicate detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have criteria based on you can find the dublicate users. Assuming you are trying to find the dublicate user based on `employeeId`. You can use the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell to check Azure AD for duplicate attributes.

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "employeeId  eq 'M10584114'" |Select-Object DisplayName,UserPrincipalName
```

[image]